# Android Things with Raspberry Pi 3 - Unable to bring up launcher

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, adb, android-things

I am attempting to set up my Android Things device on a new network and realized that, as I had an app preloaded on device, I am never getting to the Launcher and thus am never getting access to the the IP address required for connecting via ADB. Is there a way that I can interface with the Raspberry Pi or reach the launcher so that I can connect it to the internet without wiping the SD Card and replacing it with stock Android Things?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41500019/115145

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731108/how-to-set-wifi-to-android-things-without-an-ethernet-cable-or-adb ?

Comment: since you have an app pre-installed. You can have it blink an led in morse code to tell you the ip ;-)

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare for the link! This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41500020/4663107

Answer (score 0):

you hava two method :

1. connect old network and connect adb use `pm uninstall packagename` unintall you apk
2. use serial debug console follow  [this link](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html)

Comment: @Onik yes i know i just give he method ,when next connect new network just uninstall old apk and i will edit my answer.